# Evitar agregar elementos a un ArraList por referencia

Tags: java

Tengo esta clase:

```
class Persona {
    private List<String> correos;
    
    public void setCorreos(List<String> correos) {
        this.correos = correos;
    }
    
    public List<String> getCorreos() {
        return correos;
    }
}
```

En otro lugar tengo este método:

```
private void modificaCorreos( Persona persona ) {
    List<String> correos = persona.getCorreos();
    correos.add("mibanco@mibanco.com");
}
```

En otro lugar, imprimo la lista correos y se imprime el correo "mibanco@mibanco.com", vi un ejemplo en internet y para evitar que agreguen el correo a la clase Persona en el getter de Correos hacen:

```
public List<String> getCorreos() {
    return new ArrayList<String>(correos);
}
```

Pero la verdad no entiendo como funciona.

Comment: Es porque el método te regresa una copia de la lista de correos.

Comment: Cuando haces `return correos;`  en `getCorreos` no estás devolviendo una nueva lista de correos, estás devolviendo una referencia a la lista correos de la clase Persona. Cualquier operación que se haga con esa referencia modificará la variable correos de la clase persona. En cambio, retornando `new ArrayList<String>(correos);` estás retornando una copia de los correos del usuario, no una referencia. Como es una copia, la variable original no se modifica al realizar cualquier operación.

Comment: Pero al pasarse por referencia, no se ve afectada la lista original? A final de cuentas lo que se va creando son referencias, no?

Comment: Cuando retornas la variable directamente (retornas una referencia), por tanto SI se ve afectada la variable original. Cuando retornas una copia: `new ArrayList<String>(correos);`, la variable original se mantiene intacta. Si te causa duda lo que hace esa línea, basicamente crea una NUEVA lista, COPIANDO el contenido de la lista correos.